# Add Table from different databases on crystal reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, crystal-reports, datasource

Im using Crystal Reports to connect to my SQL Server Database from an ERP(PRIMAVERA).
The Problem is, there's a default report that i want to change and put more fields.
The user who created the report, used the same tables as i want to use, but one, that is not in my database. 
I want to add a new table to the Datasource, thats from another Database(my database) to the default report that i want to edit(wich has the default datasource same as mine, but one table different).
Is it possible? If it is, how can i do it?

Comment: Not sure if you can point your data source to multiple databases. but inside your sql query you can use Three Part name to use tables across multiple databases i.e `[Database].[Schema].[Object]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. In the Database Expert, simply choose (or create) the connection to the 2nd database. Then add the table to the report. Crystal will give you a warning, but you can bypass that and use the table.

If the report is being used as part of another application, it may not work, but if your running from Crystal, there should be no problem.